# A problem in leetcode! Reverse Linked List

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem about python.
I don't know the problem of my code.

```
pre, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, pre 
cur.next, pre, cur = pre, cur, cur.next
```

The fist line can not work and the second line can work!
What's the difference between them?
Thanks you so much!

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.  
# class ListNode:  
#     def __init__(self, x):  
#         self.val = x  
#         self.next = None  

class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        pre, cur = None, head
        while cur:
            #pre, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, pre
            cur.next, pre, cur = pre, cur, cur.next 
        return pre
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your two lines

```
pre, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, pre 
cur.next, pre, cur = pre, cur, cur.next
```

is that in the first one you're changing the value of cur before you change the value of cur.next, but in the second one you're changing the value of cur.next before you change the value of cur. So in the two lines you're changing the next field of different ListNodes.